# Why recovery took longer time even though analysis phase is not that long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore, recovery

We are doing Volume Snapshot restoration from Production to Warm Stand-By Server on daily basis. Daily it takes around 10 mins for DB to recover. But yesterday it took 44 mins to recover.

I am confused on where exactly the time was spent (analysis only took ~12.5 minutes) and once I identify that I want to know why it happened and how can we fix it.

**Message**

> Recovery completed for database XXXXXXX (database ID 7) in 2612
>   second(s) (analysis 748452 ms, redo 0 ms, undo 814 ms.) This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.

Note: There are only 53 VLFs in the log file, ranging in size from 6 MB to 244 MB (auto growth setting for the log file is 10%).

Total DB Size: 4598 MB
Log File Size: 2698 MB

Version info:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU8) (KB4505830) - 13.0.5426.0 (X64) Jul 21 2019 21:16:47 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Are those VLF large ? if there was a lot (some GB for example) of transaction to redo/undo in the log file, that could explain why it took longer to recover.

Comment: What is output of `select @@version`. Its difficult to tell what caused analysis phase to take time but it was trying to ascertain amount of rollback and roll forward it has to do